# Laravel - Display form results on the same page after mutliple forms submit

Tags: php, laravel

I have a three pages. Two of them are with forms which submit to another page. 
These are my routes:

```
Route::get('brandspendings', 'BrandSpendingsController@index')->middleware('premium');

Route::post('brandSpendingsSearch', 'BrandSpendingsController@search')->middleware('premium')->name('bsSearch');

Route::post('brandSpendingsFilter', 'BrandSpendingsController@search2')->middleware('premium')->name('bsFilter');
```

And the process is like this:

1. Users search for some term (on `brandspendings` index page)
2. List found items based on first search (`brandSpendingsSearch`. Here users select wanted items (checkbox) and proceed to third page
3. The results and tables are displayed on this page

How can I make this all happen on first page `brandspendings` so that when users search for term the form redirects back to `brandspendings` with appended results... and after (step 2. in the list) selecting checkboxes again redirect back to  `brandspendings` with results from the third step.

Problem for me is because Laravel returns one blade per controller and route (in my knowledge). Is it possible for all these actions to preform on single page (`brandspendings`)?

Right now it is like this:

```
public function index(){
    return view('brandspendings.brandSpendings', compact('bsUserSearch'));
}

public function search(){
    return view('brandspendings.brandSpendingsSearch', compact('idAndProducts', 'count', 'media', 'dateFrom', 'dateUntil', 'country', 'company'));
}

public function search2(){
    return view('brandspendings.brandSpendingsFilter', compact('campaignID', 'campaign', 'chart2', 'table', 'suma', 'products', 't',
            'nrOfCampaigns', 'company', 'dateFrom', 'dateUntil', 'media', 'country'));
}
```

Comment: Use Ajax calls to make such things on same page

Comment: There is no other solution? I have a lot of data. Ajax doesn't seem like a good option for me at the moment.

Comment: I don't know about other solutions and I hope you will get solution from other people here.